# Trace table for egg drop

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, dynamic-programming

Two Egg problem:

> You are given 2 eggs.
>   You have access to a 100-storey building.
>   Eggs can be very hard or very fragile means it may break if dropped from the first floor or may not even break if dropped from 100 th floor.Both eggs are identical.
>   You need to figure out the highest floor of a 100-storey building an egg can be dropped without breaking.
>   Now the question is how many drops you need to make. You are allowed to break 2 eggs in the process.

I know the solution for this problem with dynamic programming. I want to trace the solution along with the minimum number of tries. i.e the floors that I have to try for getting the minimum number of tries.

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <limits.h>


// A utility function to get maximum of two integers
int max(int a, int b) { return (a > b)? a: b; }


/* Function to get minimum number of trails needed in worst
  case with n eggs and k floors */
int eggDrop(int n, int k)
{
    /* A 2D table where entery eggFloor[i][j] will represent minimum
       number of trials needed for i eggs and j floors. */
    int eggFloor[n+1][k+1];
    int res;
    int i, j, x;

    // We need one trial for one floor and0 trials for 0 floors
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        eggFloor[i][1] = 1;
        eggFloor[i][0] = 0;
    }

    // We always need j trials for one egg and j floors.
    for (j = 1; j <= k; j++)
        eggFloor[1][j] = j;

    // Fill rest of the entries in table using optimal substructure
    // property
    for (i = 2; i <= n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 2; j <= k; j++)
        {
            eggFloor[i][j] = INT_MAX;
            for (x = 1; x <= j; x++)
            {
                res = 1 + max(eggFloor[i-1][x-1], eggFloor[i][j-x]);
                if (res < eggFloor[i][j])
                    eggFloor[i][j] = res;
            }
        }
    }

    // eggFloor[n][k] holds the result
    return eggFloor[n][k];
}

/* Driver program to test to pront printDups*/
int main()
{
    int n = 2, k = 36;
    printf ("\nMinimum number of trials in worst case with %d eggs and "
             "%d floors is %d \n", n, k, eggDrop(n, k));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If I have understood correctly, for 100 storeys and two eggs, shouldn't the answer be worst case 50?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to store the value of x that gives you the optimal solution:

```
int eggDrop(int n, int k)
{
    /* A 2D table where entery eggFloor[i][j] will represent minimum
       number of trials needed for i eggs and j floors. */
    int eggFloor[n+1][k+1];
    int floor[n+1][k+1];
    int res;
    int i, j, x;

    // We need one trial for one floor and0 trials for 0 floors
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        eggFloor[i][1] = 1;
        eggFloor[i][0] = 0;
    }

    // We always need j trials for one egg and j floors.
    for (j = 1; j <= k; j++)
        eggFloor[1][j] = j;

    // Fill rest of the entries in table using optimal substructure
    // property
    for (i = 2; i <= n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 2; j <= k; j++)
        {
            eggFloor[i][j] = INT_MAX;
            for (x = 1; x <= j; x++)
            {
                res = 1 + max(eggFloor[i-1][x-1], eggFloor[i][j-x]);
                if (res < eggFloor[i][j]) {
                    eggFloor[i][j] = res;
                    floor[i][j] = x;
                }                        
            }
        }
    }

    // eggFloor[n][k] holds the result
    return eggFloor[n][k];
}
```

In the end, `floor[i][j]` contains the floor you need to try when you have `i` eggs and `j` floors.